# Disabled Haml field is not passed to my rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a single form which has some input fields. This form, firstly get values from database and fill them in. If they have value they will be disabled.

```
=text_field_tag("dt|#{a_key}",(begin;a_mock["dt_open"];rescue;nil;end), :class => "form-control",  :disabled => a_mock["active"] == "true" )
```

In my rb file there is a rule which validate date. If the field is blank:

```
if !dt_open.blank?
   ...
end
```

What I noticed is if the field are disabled, it doesn't send. I know because I print the message and the field aren't there.
How can overcome this behavior in haml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input with `disabled` `attribute` will not submitted, you can user `readonly` rather `disabled`, did the almost same thing you can not change or edit input field value.

**Another solution**

If you still want to use the `disabled` `attribute` the you can apply the following javascript to allow submit the `disabled`

```
 <script>
     $('#your_form_id').submit(function() {
          $("#disabled_input_field_id").prop('disabled', false);
          //your code goes here
     })
 </script>
```

Comment: I didn't know about the readonly property. After I found out the problem was solved. The value is passed perfectly. Your answer solves.

Comment: Good to know it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`hidden_field_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag) that will post the value on submit. I would also just print the value in a `p` tag instead of showing a disabled text input, but that is just my opinion.

```
- if a_mock["active"] == "true"
  = hidden_field_tag "dt|#{a_key}", a_mock["dt_open"]
  p= a_mock["dt_open"]
- else    
  = text_field_tag "dt|#{a_key}", a_mock["dt_open"], class: "form-control"
```